# how to Create webvtt file for subtitle dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jwplayer

> i am trying to create the web vtt file dynamically where user pauses , and player should be able to do get the current playtime than user can write subtitle ....

i am trying to give user a screen as well .. so that he can see what is he doing 
after user is finished writing subtitle

i want to save the file in web vtt format for subtitle

is it possible ?? than how ?? pls guide me ???

i got some help from here because it does look like what i have in mind 
[html 5 wepage video subtitle](http://scottbw.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/creating-subtitles-and-audio-descriptions-with-html5-video/)

[HTML5 VIDEO CAPTION MAKER](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/CaptionMaker/)

ONE MORE THING I AM TRYING TO DO THIS IN JWPLAYER

Comment: Possible? Yes, but it is quite a big task and probably too broad a scope for Stackoverflow. Try breaking it down into smaller chunks and addressing them one at a time.

Comment: ok lets start it with u know .... like having a web page with multiple text box

like 

start time 
end time

message

Comment: The JW Player does support VTT files. Not really sure about dynamic creation, though...

Comment: @EthanLongTail  : than which file format it support for subtitle

Comment: @EthanLongTail     http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28845/adding-video-captions     ......................... in this link it is mentioned that it support three format including vtt ?????