# How to display the jwplayer video caption in own division

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

i am using JWplayer for my videos

my player design will be hiding jwplayer control bar having my own control and than below the video i need to have caption not over the video so that view of the video is not hidden.

using inspect element i got the caption ID and CLASS (my-video_div_caption/jwcaptions)
If i try to somehow read the caption using jquery to listen to changes within a div and act accordingly (like [Listen to changes within a DIV and act accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712124/jquery-listen-to-changes-within-a-div-and-act-accordingly))

than it is only reflected in HTML5 not in flash

if override the css it is only reflected in HTML5 not flash ([show subtitle outside of player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997784/show-subtitle-outside-of-player))

Now if i use the JWplayer api (which will help functionality to work in both HTML5 and flash)

```
function getCurrentCaptions1() {
    $("#Caption_track").html("The current captions track is: " + jwplayer().getCurrentCaptions());
 };
function getCaptionsList1() {
    var levels = jwplayer().getCaptionsList();
    var text = "The list of captions tracks is: ";
    if(levels) { 
        for (var i=0; i < levels.length; i++) { 
            text += levels[i].label +", ";
        }
    } else { text += "-  "; }
    appendLog(text.substr(0,text.length-2));
};
function setCurrentCaptions1() {
    var level = prompt("Set the captions track","1");
    if(level != undefined) {
        jwplayer().setCurrentCaptions(level);
    }
};

jwplayer().onCaptionsList(function captionsList(event) {
    console.log(event);
    var text = "List of captions tracks changed to: ";
    for (var i=0; i < event.tracks.length; i++) { 
        text += event.tracks[i].label +", ";
    }
    appendLog(text.substr(0,text.length-2));
});
jwplayer().onCaptionsChange(function captionsChange(event) {
    appendLog("Current captions track changed to: "+event.track);
});

function appendLog(text) {
    var log = document.getElementById("log");
    var inner = log.innerHTML;
    log.innerHTML = inner + text + "<br/>";
};
```

Using Above Code i can only find below stuff
 1. current captions track
 2. list of captions tracks
 3.Set the current captions track

but my requirement is to have the caption in my own division below the video (if possible in my own division ) in both HTML5 and flash

help me in this , i can not understand how to do it using javascript API of JWplayer.
or using jquery or using java script or using anything .....

Thank you for help 
 Really appreciate all the genius of stack overflow ...thank you all

i am just beginner here but i am loving it 
thanks guys :)

Best
-Hitesh

P.S.
( previously i asked one question which i didnt get answer till now 
[how to Create webvtt file for subtitle dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678092/how-to-create-webvtt-file-for-subtitle-dynamically)
if it is possible pls answer that question as well ...thanks :)  )

Comment: I'm currently working with jwPlayer and looking to do something similar within the next week. I'll try to keep your question in mind and hit this back up when I get to my solution. Good luck for now!

Comment: @SpYk3HH:Thanks :).... Are you from JWplayer developer team

Comment: Lol. No. Just picked it up. I just finished reskinning it and connecting it to a db. Its pretty fun!

Comment: hmmm nice @SpYk3HH ....   thanks for trying it ... let me know if u got some idea

Comment: The captions being outside of the player is not something we can easily support.

Comment: @EthanLongTail: i agree :( i am also struggling for long time :(

Comment: Yes, but this isn't isn't a common request, so we don't have a high demand to support this out of the box.

Comment: I understand that not many ppl want this ... we dont want the caption to hide the tutorial video which has video content for user to learn 
that is why we want caption to be below the video  -Hitesh

Comment: @SpYk3HH:hi there ....just wanted to know if you were able to bring the caption below or how far did u go ???